# Error in the results of 'hexo generate && hexo deploy'

Tags: hexo

After I type: $ hexo generate && hexo deploy

I got this information and there's no hint of error's reason.

```
FATAL Something's wrong. Maybe you can find the solution here: http://hexo.io/docs/troubleshooting.html

Error
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\hexo\blog\node_modules\hexo-util\lib\spawn.js:37:17)

at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)

at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)

at ChildProcess.cp.emit (D:\hexo\blog\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:29)

at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)

at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:342:11)

at emitOne (events.js:96:13)

at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)

at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:497:12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe some errors occur in the process of `npm install` or `npm install -g hexo-cli`. There is no methods but reinstall the environment of hexo.

Steps：

1. `cd D:\hexo\blog` , and `npm uninstall hexo`
2. `cd D:\hexo` , and `rm -rf blog`
3. `npm install -g hexo-cli`
4. `hexo init blog`
5. `npm install`
6. `npm install hexo-deployer-git --save`
7. `hexo d -g`

If hexo deploy error again, you can reinstall nodejs and npm, and update nodejs to the latest version (nodejs is not always reliable).

You can scan [my Blog](http://yanss.top) (build with hexo and github, CI by AppVeyor).
and the source files are there
 [image]
I'll add a blog about how to build a personal Blog with hexo and github, and how to make it auto-deploy (CI, search it in wiki) by the third service such as AppVeyor and Travis CI.

Comment: what's the meaning of "flagged"? i'm not quite sure of it. Well, the purpose of writing blogs is not self promotion?

Comment: ok, thx u a lot, i have update my answer to follow the help documentation.

Comment: You will probably also want to read: "[What signifies "Good" self promotion?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212)" It's not that you can't link to your own blog, it's that you need to be careful doing so. Particularly, your answers always must be actual answers to the question and stand alone without the user *needing* to go to your blog to get the actual answer (they can go to your blog to get *more* information, but the Answer needs to be an actual answer without the blog), and you *must* disclose that it's your blog, as you did here in this answer.

Comment: I realize it now, thank you. And the reason why I link to my blog is that I have experienced the same problem as the questioner, but I haven't record the steps how I solve the problem. And I'll new a blog about it tonight or tomorrow, maybe it can offer help to questioner.

Comment: @yanss, No problem. I commented mostly to provide the additional link. BTW: If you want a specific user to be notified of your comment, you need to include their ID in your comment with an `@` in front of it. For instance, I would be `@Makyen`. If you do this as the first thing in your comment, the system will provide auto-complete suggestions from those who have already posted comments on that answer/question. The original poster of the answer/question on which you are commenting will always be notified. This [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/271271) has more information.

Comment: @Makyen OK, I get it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used git to deploy before I realize your answer. I will try update node.js and give you my progress.